# Problem with Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, json

Im having this weird problem with creating Json dynamically.... for some reason this doesnt work

```
var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
                from company in companies
                select new
                {
                    i = company.Id,
                    cell = new string[] { company.Id.ToString(), "<a href=\""+Url.Action("Edit",new{id=company.Id})+"\">"+company.Name.ToString()+"</a>" }
                }).ToArray()
        };
```

Its giving me a weird "Could not translate expression....... into sql" exception

but with this minor change it works just fine

```
var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = (
                    from company in companies
                    select new
                    {
                        i = company.Id,
                        cell = new string[] { company.Id.ToString(), "<a href=\""+Url.Action("Edit",new{id=5})+"\">"+company.Name.ToString()+"</a>" }
                    }).ToArray()
            };
```

Notice that the change is just to make id=5 instead of dynamic.

also, this works correctly but I dont like it.

```
var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
                from company in companies
                select new
                {
                    i = company.Id,
                    cell = new string[] { company.Id.ToString(), "<a href=\"Edit/"+company.Id+"\">"+company.Name.ToString()+"</a>" }
                }).ToArray()
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but assuming `companies` is an IQueryable from the DataContext, try calling ToList() on it so that the select expression doesn't get sent to the database.

```
var jsonData = new
{
    total = totalPages,
    page = page,
    records = totalRecords,
    rows = (
        from company in companies.ToList()
        select new
        {
            i = company.Id,
            cell = new string[] { company.Id.ToString(), "<a href=\""+Url.Action("Edit",new{id=company.Id})+"\">"+company.Name.ToString()+"</a>" }
        }).ToArray()
};
```

Comment: Groovy. Go go stab in the dark!

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to translate the `i` to SQL and failing. The query that gets generated is something close to

```
SELECT companies.Id,
    '<a href=\"Edit/' + companies.Id + '\">' + companies.Name + '</a>'
FROM companies
```

Basically, your string concatenation is being sent to your SQL server.

Comment: But it isnt failing... the only one that fails is the first one... the difference is that in the first one I use Url.Action wheres in the third one i use hard coded url.

Comment: So is it failing when trying to send Url.Action() to SQL? Do you get a SQL error message similar to "URL.Action() contains no valid translation to SQL"?